# Номер и название Тильды (~) в System.Windows.Input.Key

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Под каким номером и названием находится тильда в System.Windows.Input.Key и есть ли она там вообще ?

Comment: В соответствии с [документацией](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.key?view=windowsdesktop-7.0): `OemTilde` 146 Клавиша OEM с тильдой.

Comment: [тут](https://snipp.ru/handbk/js-kbd-codes) почему-то тильда под 192 номером, [здесь](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.key?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) 146

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В перечислении `System.Windows.Input.Key` эта клавиша будет `Key.Oem3` или `Key.OemTilde`

```
public enum Key
{
    //...

    // The OEM 3 key.
    Oem3 = 146,
    // The OEM Tilde key.
    OemTilde = 146,

    // ...
}
```

Код клавиши - 146

Документация: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.key

Comment: По данной ссылке находится: `OemTilde 146 "Клавиша OEM с тильдой."`

Comment: @igoefi дважды не заметили, я поправил ответ